# Calculating song's FFT in Android

Tags: android, fft

I'm building small android app for kids, which simply plays melody, then child tries to sing back. I record and compare with song for saying you sang correctly etc.

So far, I managed to record and calculate real time data from microphone with TarsosDSP.I also projected into a graph. But I can't get the FFT values of melodies. I'm really new on audio processing area.

Can someone give me an example of how to calculate FFT of simple mp3 file? 
Thanks.

Comment: one thing is transforming into frequency spectrum, another thing is melody extraction. the first is easy you can use JTransform library or maybe use a native c implementation. for melody extraction if you can do it, please share the solution

Comment: FFTs are bad for pitch estimation.  Melody extraction is a advanced level research topic.  See: http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/Audio_Melody_Extraction for academic papers on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the song into bytes, then you can use this code.

I used the JTranforms library and it works perfectly, you can compare it to the function used by Matlab.

here is my code with comments referencing how matlab transforms any signal and gets the frequency amplitudes (https://la.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)

first, add the following in the build.gradle (app)

```
implementation 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
```

and here it is the code for for transforming a simple sine wave, works like a charm

```
double Fs = 8000;
double T = 1/Fs;
int L = 1600;

double freq = 338;

double sinValue_re_im[] = new double[L*2]; // because FFT takes an array where its positions alternate between real and imaginary
for( int i = 0; i < L; i++)
{
    sinValue_re_im[2*i] = Math.sin( 2*Math.PI*freq*(i * T) ); // real part
    sinValue_re_im[2*i+1] = 0; //imaginary part
}

// matlab
// tf = fft(y1);

DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(L);
fft.complexForward(sinValue_re_im);
double[] tf = sinValue_re_im.clone();

// matlab
// P2 = abs(tf/L);
double[] P2 = new double[L];
for(int i=0; i<L; i++){

    double re = tf[2*i]/L;
    double im = tf[2*i+1]/L;
    P2[i] = sqrt(re*re+im*im);
}

// P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
double[] P1 = new double[L/2]; // single-sided: the second half of P2 has the same values as the first half
System.arraycopy(P2, 0, P1, 0, L/2);
// P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
System.arraycopy(P1, 1, P1, 1, L/2-2);
for(int i=1; i<P1.length-1; i++){
    P1[i] = 2*P1[i];
}
// f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
double[] f = new double[L/2 + 1];
for(int i=0; i<L/2+1;i++){
    f[i] = Fs*((double) i)/L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the AudioProcessor from ExoPlayer and use this FFT wrapper to get the data [Noise](https://github.com/paramsen/noise)

Answer (score -1):

Spectrum Analysis using Java, Sampling Frequency, Folding Frequency, and the FFT Algorithm http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3380031